# Accumulative / Integrative fractals?

Tags: analysis, reference-request, recreational-mathematics, fractals

**For context** this question is slightly related to [this question on parameter paths for fractal animations](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1462728/213607)

---

Most fractals I know about iterate some function and then output a color which is a function of some decision. For example Mandelbrot and Julia fractals outputs a color which is a function of the number of iterations $i$ where binary decision $|z_i|>k$ first (the lowest such $i$) gets triggered.

Can we build fractals which instead are functions of discrete sums or integrals?

I made an attempt here with iteration $$z_t =c+{(z_{t-1})}^{t\alpha}$$
and sum / integral:
$$I = \sum_{i=0}^{32} \exp(-|z_t|^{1/2})\arg(z_t)$$

For one fixed value of $\alpha$ this gives us a function $\mathbb C\to \mathbb R$. Here is an animation on $$\mathcal R \in [-1/2,1/2], \mathcal I\in[-1/3,1/3] \text{ for } \alpha \in [1,1.5]$$
(Many thanks to user @Peter Taylor who showed me how to get this animation format working.)
[image: $\alpha$]

**So to the question** I am looking for other fractals of the same kind: being possible to express as functions involving integrals / sums of iterated self references. Any reference or homemade one is welcome.

Here is last term only, as requested by @Rahul :

[image]

Comment: Not an answer, but have you tried drawing just the last term in your sum, i.e. $\exp(-|z_{32}|^{1/2})\arg(z_{32})$? I'm curious whether most of the fractal nature of the plot is coming from the later terms, and the early ones are just serving to reduce the contrast.

Comment: @Rahul you may be right, I have not checked it. I first thought the lack of contrast was dependent on the exponent in the exp, but I have not tried very many of those either.